# VBA Do Loop Doesnt Work

Tags: excel, loops, vba

I created the following `Do` loop:

```
    Sub Test2()
Set sht = Worksheets("Calculations")
LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
LastCol = (LastRow - 2) * 3
i = 1
r = 3
c = 5

Do Until r > LastRow
    sht.Cells(r, c).Select
    RangeName = "Airline_" & i
    Set Cell = sht.Cells(r, 5)
    sht.Names.Add Name:=RangeName, RefersTo:=Cell
        Do Until c > LastCol
            RangeName = "Airline_" & i
            Set Cell = Application.Union(Range("Airline_" & i), sht.Cells(r, c))
            sht.Names.Add Name:=RangeName, RefersTo:=Cell
        c = c + 3
        Loop
    i = i + 1
    r = r + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

At first glance, everything appears to be OK. But when `r` becomes 4, it looks like the `Do until c > LastCol` doesn't work.

Below are some screenshots, as explanation:

First row, which works:
[image: Screenshot 1 (working row)]

Second row, which isn't working:
[image: Screenshot 2 (not working)]

Comment: You probably need to set `c = 5` before the start of your `Do Until c > LastCol` loop, otherwise `c` still has the value it had at the end of the previous loop.  (I'm not sure what the purpose of your `sht.Cells(r, c).Select` is - you may actually need to set `c=5` before that line, but it would probably be better to just move that line down below the bottom of the `r` loop to be honest.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer FOR loops.

Also there was a lot of redundancy.

```
Sub Test2()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim Lastrow&, LastCol&
Dim r&, c&
Dim RangeName as String

Set sht = Worksheets("Calculations")
Lastrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
LastCol = (Lastrow - 2) * 3 'need to be careful with this, too many rows will go off the page in columns.


For r = 3 To Lastrow
    RangeName = "Airline_" & r - 2
    Set cell = sht.Cells(r, 5)
    For c = 8 To LastCol Step 3
        Set cell = Union(cell, sht.Cells(r, c))
    Next c
    sht.Names.Add Name:=RangeName, RefersTo:=cell
Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: Keep going - get rid of `RangeName` and just set it in the `Name:=` (or declare it at least!)

Comment: Knew I had missed one.  I prefer to use variables as it helps with debugging. @YowE3K

Comment: Fair enough - I'm also worried about `Lastrow = ... + 1` - that seems like a fudge just so that `LastCol` is calculated correctly

Comment: I agree that the math seems a little wonky, but I don't know enough to do anything about it.  I mean why would you name a range that is empty.

Comment: Data seems to be a grid of exchange rates (or similar) so that there are the same number of rows as "columns" (where each "column" is 3 Excel columns wide).  So there is really only one variable that needs to be calculated - number of data points - and that could be used for both x and y coordinates.  But I am too lazy to think about it too much, so was glad when you posted an answer :D

Comment: Thank you! This helps me a lot!